# RemoveOutputCacheItem broken after adding querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC 3 I was outputcaching a JsonResult like this:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 21600, VaryByParam = "None", VaryByCustom = "tenant")]
    public JsonResult NotifyTasks(int id) {
         return Json(new {pending = 5}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

The URL to get the JSON was:

```
http://localhost/foo/notifytasks/1
```

At times I invalidate the cache pages with a simple

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("foo/notifytasks");
```

The method signature has changed and RemoveOutputCacheItem no longer works. The URL now has the querystring **?status=Status1** appended and this broke RemoveOutputCacheItem.

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 21600, VaryByParam = "None", VaryByCustom = "tenant")]
    public JsonResult NotifyTasks(int id, string status) {
         return Json(new {pending = 5}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
http://localhost/foo/notifytasks/1?status=Status1
```

How do I get RemoveOutputCacheItem to work with an appended querystring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, I think it comes down to that [RemoveOutputCacheItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/914c7ktw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) only accepts a path and a querystring is not part of the path (path <> url ?).

If you would register a seperate route

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "DifferentRoute", 
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{status}", 
   new { controller = "Information", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, status = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

then `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("foo/notifytasks/1/Status1");` works fine.

I hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. I ended-up doing this and things are working fine again.